# Docker Compose - Ocelot Api GetWay - Call API

Tags: asp.net, docker, api, docker-compose, ocelot

I have on question about docker,

I have my api called **IdentityService** for example with this configuration,
launchsetting.json:

```
 "IdentityService": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5002"
    }
```

My docker File of Identity -> EXPOSE 3000

Another project called, **OcelotApiGateway**

launchsetting.json:

```
 "OcelotApiGateway": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001"
    },
```

My docker File of Ocelot -> EXPOSE 3001

ocelot.json

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Identity/{Id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5002
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Identity/{Id}",
      "GatewayOptions": {
        "Timeout": 3000,
        "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:4592"
      }
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {}
}
```

When I run this two project without docker it works, *https://localhost:5001/api/Identity/54325*

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpP7e.png)

But when I run this project with docker-compose it doesn't works, my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  ocelotapigateway:
    container_name: api-gateway
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}ocelotapigateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: OcelotApiGateway/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 4592:3001
  identityservice:
    container_name: identityservice
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}identityservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: IdentityService/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 4593:3000
```

And I don't find the error, anyone can help me?
Maybe it's for the https... I don't know..
Thanks a lot to all community!

I try to call *https://localhost:4592/api/Identity/641ee2820974a1c9b854c56e* and see the same results because I use docker to redirect the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I saw that my configuration wasn't correct,

For example;
IdentityService Configuration;

```
Launch Settings JSON;
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5117"
DOCKERFILE EXPOSE 80
```

Ocelot Configuration;

```
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5075"
DOCKERFILE EXPOSE 80
```

ocelot.json;

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Identity/{Id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "identityservice",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Identity/{Id}"
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:3001"
  }
}
```

Finally my docker compose,

```
networks:
  backend:

services:
  ocelotapigateway:
    container_name: api-gateway
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}ocelotapigateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: OcelotApiGateway/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 3001:80
    networks:
        - backend
  identityservice:
    container_name: identityservice
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}identityservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: IdentityService/Dockerfile
    networks:
        - backend
```